# jquery bind events to multiple buttons

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jQuery and struggling with the following:

I have 6 `buttons`, all with a '+' icon. When you click one `button`, some content will appear and the '+' icon will change into a '-' icon. After clicking that same button, the corresponding content should disappear and this '-' icon should turn back into the '+' icon.

When content A is open and you click on another `button`, content A should disappear and content B should show up. Off course with the same action on the '+' and '-' icons. So far I have this code and it working just fine. I know that you can write this code in a much shorter way, but my question is how?

**My code so far:**

```js
// Button One
$(".btnOne").click(function() {
    var value = $(".btnOne").text();
    if(value === "-") {
        $(".btnOne").text("+");
        $(".contentOne").hide(300);
    }
    else {
        $(".btnOne").text("-");
        $(".btnTwo, .btnThree, .btnFour, .btnFive, .btnSix").text("+");    
        // Show/Hide Content
        $(".contentOne").show(300);
        $(".contentTwo, .contentThree, .contentFour, .contentFive, .contentSix").hide(300);
    }
});

// Button Two
$(".btnTwo").click(function() {
    var value = $(".btnTwo").text();
    if(value === "-") {
        $(".btnTwo").text("+");
        $(".contentTwo").hide(300);
    }
    else {
        $(".btnTwo").text("-");
        $(".btnOne, .btnThree, .btnFour, .btnFive, .btnSix").text("+");    
        // Show/Hide Content
        $(".contentTwo").show(300);
        $(".contentOne, .contentThree, .contentFour, .contentFive, .contentSix").hide(300);
    }
});

// Button Three
$(".btnThree").click(function() {
    var value = $(".btnThree").text();
    if(value === "-") {
        $(".btnThree").text("+");
        $(".contentThree").hide(300);
    }
    else {
        $(".btnThree").text("-");
        $(".btnOne, .btnTwo, .btnFour, .btnFive, .btnSix").text("+");    
        // Show/Hide Content
        $(".contentThree").show(300);
        $(".contentOne, .contentTwo, .contentFour, .contentFive, .contentSix").hide(300);
    }
});

// Button Four
$(".btnFour").click(function() {
    var value = $(".btnFour").text();
    if(value === "-") {
        $(".btnFour").text("+");
        $(".contentFour").hide(300);
    }
    else {
        $(".btnFour").text("-");
        $(".btnOne, .btnTwo, .btnThree, .btnFive, .btnSix").text("+");    
        // Show/Hide Content
        $(".contentFour").show(300);
        $(".contentOne, .contentTwo, .contentThree, .contentFive, .contentSix").hide(300);
    }
});

// Button Five
$(".btnFive").click(function() {
    var value = $(".btnFive").text();
    if(value === "-") {
        $(".btnFive").text("+");
        $(".contentFive").hide(300);
    }
    else {
        $(".btnFive").text("-");
        $(".btnOne, .btnTwo, .btnThree, .btnFour, .btnSix").text("+");    
        // Show/Hide Content
        $(".contentFive").show(300);
        $(".contentOne, .contentTwo, .contentThree, .contentFour, .contentSix").hide(300);
    }
});

// Button Six
$(".btnSix").click(function() {
    var value = $(".btnSix").text();
    if(value === "-") {
        $(".btnSix").text("+");
        $(".contentSix").hide(300);
    }
    else {
        $(".btnSix").text("-");
        $(".btnOne, .btnTwo, .btnThree, .btnFour, .btnFive").text("+");    
        // Show/Hide Content
        $(".contentSix").show(300);
        $(".contentOne, .contentTwo, .contentThree, .contentFour, .contentFive").hide(300);
    }
});
```

Part of the HTML:

```html
<!-- Nav Buttons -->
<nav>
  <div class="btnOne" title="Button One">+</div>
  <div class="btnTwo" title="Button Two">+</div>
  <div class="btnThree" title="Button Three">+</div>
</nav>

<!-- Content -->
<article class="dynamicContent">
  <section class="contentOne">
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="contentTwo">
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="contentThree">
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code? It would help to give you a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a common class to `<button>`'s and target element and use common class to attach event handlers to them.

In the event handler use current element context i.e. `this` and persist the selector target using custom `data-*` attribute which can be fetched using `.data(key)` method

```js
$(".btns").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  var target = $($(this).data('target'))
  if (value === "-") {
    $(this).text("+");
    target.hide(300);
  } else {
    $(this).text("-");
    $(".btns").not(this).text("+");

    // Show/Hide Content
    target.show(300);
    $(".content").not(target).hide(300);
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Nav Buttons -->
<nav>
  <div class="btns" title="Button One" data-target=".contentOne">+</div>
  <div class="btns" title="Button Two" data-target=".contentTwo">+</div>
  <div class="btns" title="Button Three" data-target=".contentThree">+</div>
</nav>

<!-- Content -->
<article class="dynamicContent">
  <section class="content contentOne">
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </section>
  <section class="content contentTwo">
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </section>
  <section class="content contentThree">
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </section>
</article>
```